# WPF Access of Cell in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

i have a big problem and i am searching for a long time but i dont find the answer so i ask here now.
I know how get Column and Row of something what i clicked and can set UI Elements but i cant check if for example a playstone is on row 1 and column 1 . 
How i get access for a specif cell , i want check if a specific cell is a button or empty.
Thanks for everyone who tries to answer this question.

What i know:
How to get rows:

```
 Button btn = sender as Button;
                var Spalte = Grid.GetColumn(btn);
                var Zeile = Grid.GetRow(btn);
```

How to set a Element:

```
Grid.SetColumn(Spielstein, Spalte);
Grid.SetRow(Spielstein, Zeile);
```

What i dont know: Access the Cell of Row 1 and Column 1 and check if this is a Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct way of access the element by the column-row position of a Grid element, but you can write a utility method that do this, iterating over the children items of the Grid element and get the column and row position of that element like you did it before. I write an example of this utility method named GetElementInGridPosition:

The code in the window:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var element = this.GetElementInGridPosition(1, 1);
        if (element is Button)
            MessageBox.Show($"The element in 1,1 is a button.");

        element = this.GetElementInGridPosition(2, 1);
        if (element is Button)
            MessageBox.Show($"The element in 2,1 is a button.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show($"The element in 2,1 isn't a button, it's a {element.GetType().Name}.");
    }

    private UIElement GetElementInGridPosition(int column, int row) {
        foreach (UIElement element in this.RootGrid.Children) {
            if (Grid.GetColumn(element) == column && Grid.GetRow(element) == row)
                return element;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Grid Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Button</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Button in column 1, row 1</Button>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Label in column 2, row 1</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: LINQ is not invented here ^. (`var element = this.RootGrid.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(x => Grid.GetColumn(x) == column && Grid.GetRow(x) == row);`)

Answer (score 0):

Good Night!
As far as I know, it is not possible in wpf to access a specific cell in the `Grid`.
Use:

```
var Spalte = Grid.GetColumn(btn);
var Zeile = Grid.GetRow(btn);
```